# How to do Custom Paging

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, server-side, custom-paging

I want to implement server side paging in my `Silverlight` application. To get an idea of the steps that I would require I went through this [custom paging in asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/paging-and-sorting/efficiently-paging-through-large-amounts-of-data-cs/%22%20custom%20paging%20in%20asp.net%22)
article where they described how to design a `SQL` query to return the results according to the `Page Requested` and the `Total no of records per page`. I am however totally confused as to how am I going to call it from my Silverlight application. Like how am I going to specify it in the `c#` code.

The default paging using the `DataPager` is pretty simple.

```
PagedCollectionView pagingCollection = new PagedCollectionView(e.Result); //e.Result contains `List` returned by the method that calls the stored procedure GetProducts
pagerProductGrids.Source = pagingCollection;
gridProductGrid.ItemsSource = pagingCollection;
```

But I'm clueless about the procedure of doing it on my own. Like what properties I will be needing to `get` and `set` the `Page Size`, the `total no of records` etc i.e how am I going to configure my `DataGrid` and `DataPager` to pass `StartingRowIndex` and `Maximum RowcOunt`

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across [this article](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2011/10/19/paging-data-from-the-server-with-silverlight.html) a few years ago and this worked like a charme for me. I've added this to my framework and have been reusing this method ever since. The article is well explained and I believe this is exactly what you are looking for.

[Paging Data from the Server with Silverlight](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2011/10/19/paging-data-from-the-server-with-silverlight.html)

Comment: Went through the article and yes, this is what I want to implement in my Application but I have few questions: I tried Implementing the `IPagedCollection` interface in my class and tried to set the value of `TotalItemCount` but I couldn't since its a `read-only`. So my question is Can I not implement this interface in my Code behind class? Why do I need to create a custom DataSource

Comment: Quoting the article: `In order to make a generic/ re-useable implementation of this paging interface, I first created an interface that would act as the source of the data. This interface is very simple, having a single method that fetches data for the given page. The result is returned asynchronously, providing both the items within the given page and the total item count.`

Comment: Have you tried looking at the downloadable code sample at the end of the article?